# Logarithmic/Exponential Contour Integral

Tags: integration, logarithms, exponential-function, contour-integration

I have the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}$$

I believe the normal method is to apply Power series expansion on the denominator after multiplying both the top and the bottom by $e^{-x}$.  The correct answer should be $-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(2)$, and I was able to arrive at this answer.  I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this problem through contour integration?  Usually with this kind of denominator rectangular contour works.  I've tried a few, but none works well with the $\ln(x)$ in numerator. Is anyone be able to give me a hint about the choice of contour in this situation?

Comment: Integrate $\frac{z^2}{e^z+1}$ on $[r,R]\cup R e^{[0,2\pi]}\cup[R,r]\cup r e^{[2\pi,0]}$ and let $r\to 0, R\to \infty$.

Comment: Another way is to evaluate $I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1} \mathrm dx$ through Zeta functions and differentiate w.r.t. $s$.